# What's the best way to stop a click event propagating in IE9 beta?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, dojo, dom-events

`dojo.stopEvent` no longer appears to stop the default action of a click event (or a submit event) in IE9. How has the event handling changed from IE8 to IE9 and what's the best way to stop the event in IE9? `event.preventDefault()` doesn't appear to stop the click event happening either.

Comment: Looks like dojo forces IE5-8 solution on IE9... UA sniffing R bad. Try: e.cancelBubble = true; or indeed return false;

Answer (score 2):

This should be resolved as of Dojo 1.6 RC1.  Give it a try.

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0rc1/

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12257

Comment: That's good, I'm glad this is fixed, and well done for taking the initiative. However, a quick look at the patches shows that instead of using feature detection, the new code just adds yet more user-agent-based sniffing to cope with IE9. Why not rework it to use feature detection instead? That way, you end up with more maintainable code that won't need to be changed next time a new browser comes out. Obviously this change would not have been necessary had the code been written that way in the first place, but I imagine that's not your fault.

Comment: I already explained this in my comment to your answer - feature detection is a route Dojo does plan to take, but not in 1.6 - it's certainly not a change that can realistically be made across the board a week before a release.  Yes, the fix applied here currently "perpetuates" the dilemma of UA checking, but it's the low-impact change that fixes *only* the problem without affecting anything else.

Comment: I have to wonder what the point of a library like Dojo is if you can expect any code using it to break every time a new browser is released, especially when preview builds of that browser have been publicly available for a whole year before the full release.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Dojo is browser sniffing and providing IE-only implementations of event handling code based on the user agent string, and a quick look at the source code suggests this is the case too. This is bad behaviour for a general purpose library, which should be using feature detection, especially since feature detection in this case is trivially easy.

My advice: ditch Dojo, if it's too incompetent to deal with this.

Comment: Dojo does plan to visit the feature-detection route in the future (clearly won't make it for 1.6), but yes, this is becoming a known problem with IE9 on the horizon.  OTOH, are there any popular libraries out there that are known to *not* rely on UA presently?

Comment: @Ken: I'm not entirely sure. I had the impression that jQuery had made big improvements in this area around 1.3, but I haven't checked recently.

Comment: @Ken: Also, I wonder what exactly have the Dojo developers been doing. The first IE 9 preview was released in March 2010, over 10 months ago. Seems plenty of time to test their library in IE 9 to me.

Comment: Fair question (if unfairly worded), and one I had wondered a bit as well.  The dojo team made a conscious decision not to test early previews of IE9, and for good reason apparently, as even one bug I did find in it 3 months ago has been resolved as of more recent platform preview releases.  No sense aiming for a moving target, but now that the RC is on the horizon, it's planning to be investigated.

Comment: @Ken: In fairness to the Dojo devs, I would agree that writing code for the initial previews would have been foolhardy. However, even the first IE 9 preview in March 2010 had support for `addEventListener()`, for which a stable specification and several browser implementations exist, so they've had ample time to see this particular problem coming. Even longer if you consider that Dojo had feature detection enthusiast David Mark making these points and fixing them in the core about 18 months ago.

Comment: @Ken: A quick scan of jQuery's source code suggests that it uses feature detection for event handling at least and the core seems to have no reliance on the UA string at all. That doesn't rule out dodgy object inferences, and they may well have had to make changes for IE 9, but it shows it's possible for a general purpose library not to rely on the UA string.